# Как выровнять русский текст по центру PIL

Tags: python, изображения, текст, pillow, pil

Мне нужно выровнять текст на русском языке по центру (библиотека `PIL`).

Я нашел следующий код:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

W, H = (300,200)
msg = "hello"

im = Image.new("RGBA",(W,H),"yellow")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
w, h = draw.textsize(msg)
draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), msg, fill="black")

im.save("hello.png", "PNG")
```

Но он выравнивает только английский текст, а русский нет.

Answer (score 2):

Я знаю, что тема закрыта, но может кому-то пригодиться. Сегодня встретился с похожей проблемой и решение оказалось элементарным, т.к. в PIL есть специальный параметр. Без этого параметра центр текста определяется в верхнем левом углу. Параметр `anchor` он может принять несколько значений, но значение `ms` выравнивает текст по средней линии.
Вот пример кода:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

name = input('Введите имя: ')

image = Image.open('Ticket.png')
text_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", size=128)

text_draw.text(
    (540, 960), #здесь мы пишем ширину и высоту, делённые на 2
    f'{name}',
    anchor="mm",
    fill=('#FFFFFF'),
    font=font
    )

image.show()
image.save(f'Ticket-{name}.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что нужно указать шрифт, русский шрифт

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw,ImageFont

W, H = (300,200)
msg = "рузсцикя"

font=ImageFont.truetype("cour.ttf", 32, encoding='UTF-8') #cour.ttf путь к файлу с шрифтами см гугл 'скачать русский шрифт'

im = Image.new("RGBA",(W,H),"yellow")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

w, h = draw.textsize(msg,font=font) #тут
draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), msg, fill="black",font=font) #и тут

im.show()
```